# Detecting EC2 account name from inside an EC2 running instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a way for a running instance, via the meta-data facility to find out the ec2 *account* name that the instance is running under?

Looking up the meta-data service yields the following items we can query:

```
ami-id
ami-launch-index
ami-manifest-path
hostname
instance-id
local-ipv4
public-keys/
reservation-id
security-groups
```

None of which satisfy this - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the EC2 account data you need as user data to the instance. You can retrieve the user data passed to an instance by running `curl http://169.254.169.254/1.0/user-data` on the instance.

Comment: yeah already using that - but would be nice if it was automatic - but user data works fine.

Comment: is userdata only settable when you create the instance?  (I haven't found a way to tweak it after booting)

Comment: EC2 user data is set as a boot parameter and read-only afterwards.